# convert code c++ to c#

Tags: c#, c++

im trying to convert this code to c#

```
for ( int k=0; k < 3; k++ )
 if ( anim.jointInfo[j].flags & (1 << k)  ) {
        //....
 }

flags: int
jointInfo: List<>
```

Comment: And...?  What errors are you seeing, what about what you've posted doesn't work? You can't expect someone to answer this question with so few details.

Comment: That should compile fine in C#. What does the compiler say?

Comment: not enough info to help you. At a simple glance it looks like it should compile in C#.

Answer (score 7):

Gotcha, bool vs int thing

```
for ( int k=0; k < 3; k++ )
    if ( anim.jointInfo[j].flags & (1 << k) != 0) {
        //....
    }
```

Comment: if ( (anim.jointInfo[j].flags & (1 << k) ) != 0)